# shibboleth-saml with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am trying to integrate shibboleth sp with Spring-boot. The reason for not using spring saml plugin is because I have two application one is written in spring and another one is angular application which invoke spring services. I need to protect both so I kept shibboleth along apache 2.4 Red Hat. The apache will do a mod proxy to both application. The SAML is working fine and it is redirecting to my application. But I am not able to receive the attributes from Shibboleth in my application. I am able to see the attributes in shibboleth session summary page. I enabled log and I could see the attributes are getting mapped.

In my spring boot application I have written a

```
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter 
{
      @Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  //I am inspecting all attributes in request.getAttributes(), I could not find any attribute set my shibboleth.
}
```

}

My understanding is shibboleth attribute setting is enabled by default and header value is turned off by default. Could you let me know how to pass the attributes mapped in shibboleth to application?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look at https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall. It describes how to configure Apache and Tomcat/Jetty to transfer SAML attributes from Apache/SP to your app.